# Google street view API parameters to change range

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

**Google street view API**

URL: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x600&location=46.2277933992467,9.04836208165778&key=myapikey

Result: "sorry we have no imagery here"

I am looking for a specific parameter to change this "range".

Example: with "no imagery here" range is 10 meters ---> i need 50 meteres, so i will get an image.

Help me please

Thank you

Comment: See if this helps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you cannot find existing panorama in "range" using Google Maps Street View API or Metadata. There is a feature request in Google issue tracker to add a radius parameter in these APIs:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830450

Feel free to star this feature request to express your interest.

The workaround might be searching a pano ID using Google Maps JavaScript API as shown in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45282758/5140781

#### UPDATE

Good news. Google implemented feature request 35830450 and added `radius` parameter in Street View Image API.

> **radius** (default is 50) sets a radius, specified in meters, in which to search for a panorama, centered on the given latitude and longitude. Valid values are non-negative integers.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro

For your example I figured out that setting radius to 60 meters will return panorama.

Metadata request `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?location=46.2277933992467%2C9.04836208165778&radius=60&key=MY_API_KEY` returns

```
{
    "copyright":"© Google, Inc.",
    "date":"2014-11",
    "location":{
        "lat":46.22730779489779,
        "lng":9.048190155237283
    },
    "pano_id":"xB0bwJka4pfLk6hLri-t_w",
    "status":"OK"
}
```

Have a look at code snippet

```html
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=46.2277933992467%2C9.04836208165778&size=600x400&radius=60&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&signature=s7tfGqXSJ3csbFmE91-AXMieFfg=">
```